# Enabling SSL on wordpress results in 404

Tags: ssl

I'm trying to force ssl login and admin but it's not working.

I've tried going through the isecurity theme which didn't work. I then tried doing it manually by modifying my wp-config.php to include:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

However, when I go to mysite/wp-admin I get:

> The requested URL /wp-admin/ was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Taking those two lines out restores functionality. I'm using the latest version of wordpress and have the default link structure.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you checked that your server support SSL (HTTPS)?

Comment: I believe it does but it brings me to some different path. It shows me a file listing of some other folder.

Comment: Sounds like the server is pointing SSL/HTTPS to a different root. Is this in your power to change?

Comment: The correct functioning of SSL depends on correctly installed (and purchased in first place) certificate for the domain. Had you gone through this process or had hosting do it for you?

Comment: I'm happy to make a self-signed certificate. I just want the login connection encrypted. I can change where ssl/https points to -- how would I do it?

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem and the solution for me was to add these lines to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`, which is my SSL-enabled website's configuration file:

```
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```

Of course, this assumes `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`. Change accordingly if is this is different in your setup.

The thing is that Wordpress uses .htaccess rules to process the URLs and for them to work, `AllowOverride All` needs to be in the server's configuration file.

In my situation, the configuration for the non-SSL and SSL-enabled variants were in a separate files. The non-SSL configuration had `AllowOverride All` all along, and so everything was working fine. Once I had enabled the SSL, the other configuration file came into play and didn't have the required `AllowOverride All` setting.

Comment: This caused me to fist pump the air

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's easy to miss this when you're fond, as I am, of copying/pasting site configuration in Apache2.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I started getting same 404 error when I configured ssl , so I needed to add this

```
 <Directory /var/www/html/yourdomain.com/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

in this file

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf
```